# How does this JavaScript program works?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this question is not upto the level of the site i cannot find help anywhere else. I have just started to learn JavaScript but i am stuck at an example code given in my text-book

```
var a = null;
function b() {return "B";}
(a || b)();
! "B"
```

There is not enough explanation given for the code and i am not able to figure out how does it work, can anyone help me please

Thanks

Akash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the source of your confusion comes from the third and fourth line.

Let's start with the third line: `(a || b)();`.

First `a` is evaluated and if it is not `null` or `undefined` then the result of this expression is `a()`, otherwise the result is `b()`.

In your code snippet, `a` is null, so the expression is evaluated to `b()` which simply returns `"B"`.

The OR `||` operator looks at its operands one by one, until it finds a value that is *truthy* and it returns it, if all the values are *falsy* then the last operand is returned.

For more information about *truthy* and *falsy* values, [check here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Now this line `! "B"`, all strings in JavaScript are evaluated to `true` except for the empty string `""`, so the result of the previous expression is `! true` so it is `false`.

Comment: can you explain the 3rd line little bit more

Comment: @Programmer I have just added more info to my explanation, please check.

Answer (score 2):

The key is in how the `||` operator works.  This line:

```
(a || b)();
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var f;
if (a)
  f = a;
else
  f = b;
f();
```

The `||` operator works by first evaluating the left side (in this case, `a`).  It then checks to see whether that value is "truthy", which means that it's not `null`, `0`, the empty string, and a couple other things. In this case it's clearly `null`, so it's not "truthy".

Thus the `||` operator goes on to evaluate the right side (in this case, `b`), and that value is taken as the result of the `||` operation. What's "b"?  It's that little function that returns the string `"B"` when called.

Thus after the `||` operation is done, you're left with a reference to that function, and the subsequent `()` function call operator causes that function to be called.

Comment: Note that the `if` statement isn't *exactly* equivalent, because the `||` of course does not introduce another variable into the environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are two variables, `a` which is `null` and `b` which is a function that always returns the string `"B"`. `(a || b)()` demonstrates a bit how logical && and || work in JavaScript - the evaluation is [short-circuited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and the last value evaluated is the value of the entire expression. Since `a` is `null` which is falsy, `(a || b)()` evaluates to `b()`, so you get the `"B"` print.

In general:

```
(a || b);  //a if a is truthy, otherwise b
(a && b);  //a if a is falsy, otherwise b
```

Falsy values are `null`, `undefined`, `0`, the empty string `""`, `NaN` and of course `false`. Everything else is truthy.